# Rewrite URL but real URL change

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have rewrite URL code below :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /process.php?device=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

When I access : **dommain.com/test-125-ggg/data-259-data2.html** it working but all link in this web is change to **dommain.com/*test-125-ggg*/xxxxx**

**Ex :**  dommain.com/test-125-ggg/images/logo.png instead dommain.com/images/logo.png

How to fix this ?

And I want when access domain.com/process.php?device=$1&url=$2 it auto redirect to dommain.com/zzz/xxx but I don't know how to do this ?

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+process\.php\?device=([^\s&]+)&url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2.html? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /process.php?device=$1&url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

For fixing other issue use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Otherwise** you can also try adding this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.